# Why am I able to inherit & call a private constructor in a subclass?

Tags: java, subclass, private-constructor

I read that it is not possible to create a subclass from a class whose constructor is private but weirdly I am able to do it, is there something more to this snippet?

Please someone provide an easy to understand & satisfactory explanation.

```
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        app ref = new app();
        myInheritedClass myVal = ref.new myInheritedClass(10);
        myVal.show();

    }

    int myValue = 100;

    class myClass {
        int data;

        private myClass(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

    class myInheritedClass extends myClass {
        public myInheritedClass(int data) {
            super(data);
        }

        public void show() {
            System.out.println(data);
        }

    }
}
```

I ran this snippet on https://www.compilejava.net/ and the output was 10.

Comment: Why shouldnt it work? Where did you read hat? The subclass has a public constructor--that makes it accessible

Comment: @BenKnoble - `myClass` doesn't have a public constructor...

Comment: OP - please note that conventionally, Java class names begin with a CapitalLetter.

Comment: because these are **inner** classes, they both are in the *same (outer) class*.

Comment: @Olivar yes it was in a hurry i am studying for interviews thats why i didn't care about the conventions much, thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Since Java 5.0 you can access members in the same outer class even if they are private.

Comment: Using coding conventions makes your code easier for others to read. If you care about your code being read or looking professional, use the coding conventions.

Comment: The linked duplicate is not the same question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your classes are both *nested classes* (in your case, specifically *inner* classes), which means they're both part of the containing class, and so have access to all private things in that containing class, including each other's private bits.

If they weren't nested classes, you wouldn't be able to access the superclass's private constructor in the subclass.

More about nested classes in the [nested class tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) on the Oracle Java site.

This compiles, because `A` and `B` are inner classes, which are nested classes ([live copy](http://ideone.com/TtoQ3X)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Ran at " + new java.util.Date());
    }

    class A {
        private A() {
        }
    }
    class B extends A {
        private B() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles, because `A` and `B` are *static nested* classes ([live copy](http://ideone.com/2aEvpx)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Ran at " + new java.util.Date());
    }

    static class A {
        private A() {
        }
    }
    static class B extends A {
        private B() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

This *does not compile* because `A`'s constructor is private; `B` cannot access it (I don't really need `Example` in this case, but I've included it in the two above, so for context...) ([live copy](http://ideone.com/08nuZq)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Ran at " + new java.util.Date());
    }
}
class A {
    private A() {
    }
}
class B extends A {
    private B() {
        super();    // COMPILATION FAILS HERE
    }
}
```